# How can I set the same format in C# with string.Format, with different values

Tags: c#

My code to format a string

```
string.Format("{0} -> {1} {2} .{3}, {4}", A, alpha, X, beta, a);
```

And i have this values

```
A = "S'"
alpha = "S"
X = (null)
beta = (null)
a = "$"
```

output:

```
"S' -> S., $"   //ok good output
```

Now with this values:

```
A = "S'"
alpha = (null)
X = "S"
beta =(null)
a = "$"
```

output:

```
"S' ->  S ., $"  //I don't like this :(
```

how can i get the same format for both cases?

```
"S' -> S., $" //Ideal case
```

Comment: if alpha = "s" and x = "s" what's your desired output?

Comment: Downvote because the output you list for the first set of values is NOT the actual output (the actual output has two spaces after the second 'S': `S' -> S   ., $`). Also, you aren't describing very clearly what exactly you are looking for.

Comment: with alpha="S" and x="S" I wish this output `S -> S., $`

Comment: That makes it more clear...you should edit your question with that info

Comment: What if alpha="S" and x="R"?

Comment: As RufusL mentioned, the output of your first case is *not* what you wrote it is - there *are* two spaces after `alpha`, because there's a space before and after X.

Comment: Are `alpha` and `X` always mutually exclusive?

Answer (score 2):

I think you're looking for this, but it's not completely clear. Basically, if alpha is not null, it will print alpha, otherwise it will print X:

```
string.Format("{0} -> {1}.{2}, {3}", A, (alpha ?? X ), beta, a);
```

Answer (score -1):

When you use string format, first parameter will replace with {0}, second parameter with {1} and so on. when you set alpha to null and X to S the compiler replace {1} with null and {2} to S